# ¿ como ingresar varias listas dentro de un diccionario?

Tags: python-3.x

¿ si tengo varias listas como hago para meterla en un diccionario el cual tiene su clave; lo que busco es que esas listas entren dentro de una lista. 
ejemplo:{cuenta_usuario:[password[amigos],[solicitudes],[mensajes],[intereses]}. nose si se puede realizar de esta forma, si me desean colaborar enviaría el avance de mi código, es para una red socia.

Comment: Por favor revisa [ask] y danos algo del código que comenzaste, así podremos ayudarte mejor

Comment: Yo vería más adecuado un diccionario dentro de otro. El diccionario exterior tendría como clave la cuenta del usuario, y como valor un segundo diccionario. El diccionario interno tendría como claves "password", "amigos", "solicitudes", etc y como valores lo que corresponda en cada caso, lo que puede ser también una lista. Por ejemplo: `{'pepe': {'password': 'blabla', 'amigos': ['juan', 'antonio'], ...}` etc. Por cierto, evita guardar las claves en texto plano!

Comment: Naturalmente todo esto sería una especie de "simulacro", nunca una aplicación "de verdad", pues para esto último lo adecuado sería usar programación orientada a objetos, en la que cada usuario sea un objeto, y una base de datos para guardar la información, junto con un modelo de datos apropiado y un ORM como SQLAlchemy.

Comment: esta información fue muy valiosa, gracias @abulafia

Comment: @abulafia tengo un problema. puse un for que me recorriera todo un archivo.txt; ejemplo *carlos:jose,sebastian, /n *sebastian:martha,perito. la información que continua es el código  def amigos():
    sol={}
    h="amigos"
    b=open("userData.txt","r")
    for i in b:
        if "*" in i:
            i=i[i.find(":")+1:]    
            i=i[:i.find("<")]
            i=i.split(",")
            sol[h]=i
    return(sol)   
c=amigos()
print(c) pero solo me imprime el ultimo dato del archivo y no toda la información que le pido que me saque donde encuentre *

Comment: @MANUELCRISTOBALMORENOLIZCAN Mejor abres una nueva pregunta para esa cuestión, pues en un comentario el código no se lee correctamente, y quizás tampoco haya sitio para una respuesta.